# AngularJS ng-include not working Brackets vs. Tomcat

Tags: angularjs, tomcat

I'm developing an SPA using AngularJS, and using Brackets as my development tool. So far, when running it from Brackets (it behaves as a Web Server vis-à-vis Chrome), all works fine.

Now, I copied the whole project to a Linux machine running Tomcat and woops!!!... some of the pages are reported as "not found" (code 404 if I'm not mistaking).

It would appear that this has to do with the way I'm using ng-include. Here is the sample HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body slide-animate-container" ng-include src="Current_Page_in_Main_Panel">


</div>
```

where `Current_Page_in_Mail_Panel` is a variable at `$rootScope` level. On the other hand, I found that `ng-include` should be used as follows:

```
<div... ng-include src="'myURL/page'" ...>
```

(note the -'- character wrapping the page reference).

I'm also using this last syntax at other locations within the project and it works fine on both platforms (Brackets and Tomcat).

So, my question is: How should I phrase the HTML to be able to use `ng-include` and a `$rootScope` variable?

Thanks.

Comment: What does this Current_Page_in_Main_Panel variable looks like in the rootscope?

Comment: Something like: `/Pages/Sub_Pages/Application_Login.html`. This string is included in a JSON and used as-is.

Comment: So what does the network tab in developer tools say about the requests that go 404? You can look up the URL there.

Comment: It says that the file was not found (not sure is the exact phrasing, but it is the right meaning). By the way, if I try to browse the file in question y feeding it into the browser's address box, I get it correctly.